# Autowire constructor is called twice even using Qualifier in spring

Tags: java, spring, autowired, qualifiers

I am trying to learn autowire with Qualifier in spring and the autowired class constructor is called twice .
 I have the following class:

**MainApp:**

```
public class MainApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
//        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Beans.xml");
        ApplicationContext ctx =
                new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(HelloWorldConfig.class);
//        TextEditor obj = (TextEditor) ctx.getBean("helloWorld");
        TextEditor obj = (TextEditor)ctx.getBean(TextEditor.class);
        obj.spellCheck();

    }
```

**SpellChecker:**

```
public class SpellChecker {
    public SpellChecker() {
        System.out.println("Inside SpellChecker constructor.");
    }

    public void checkSpelling() {
        System.out.println("Inside checkSpelling.");
    }
```

**TextEditor**

```
public class TextEditor {

    @Qualifier("a")
    @Autowired
    private SpellChecker spellChecker;

    public SpellChecker getSpellChecker( ) {
        return spellChecker;
    }
    public void spellCheck() {
        spellChecker.checkSpelling();
    }
}
```

I have the java based configuration which has multiple bean with same Type and want to select a single bean with Qualifier but the output shows the constructor is called twice.\

**HelloWorldConfig**

```
@Component
public class HelloWorldConfig {
    @Bean
    public HelloWorld helloWorld(){
        return new HelloWorld();
    }
    @Bean
    public TextEditor textEditor(){
        return new TextEditor();
    }
    @Bean(name="a")
    public SpellChecker spellChecker(){
        return new SpellChecker();
    }
    @Bean(name="b")
    public SpellChecker spellChecker1(){
        return new SpellChecker();
    }
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
Inside SpellChecker constructor.
Inside SpellChecker constructor.
Inside checkSpelling.
```

I was expecting a single SpellChecker constructor call since i used Qualifier("a") to specify the bean, however the constructor is called twice even if I used Qualifier to select a sinlge bean. Why is it called twice??

Comment: You’ve declared two beans. Qualifier is used to select which one to inject at one specific location.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis isn't it the purpose of Qualifier to select the one bean if we have two bean  in config?

Comment: To select for the annotated injection point.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Isn't is possible to declare two beans with same type in a single config and select one bean through Qualifier?

Answer (score 0):

Check Out `HelloWorldConfig` file. You've declared 2 beans of type SpellChecker:

```
@Bean(name="a")
public SpellChecker spellChecker(){
    return new SpellChecker();
}
@Bean(name="b")    
public SpellChecker spellChecker1(){
   return new SpellChecker();
}
```

Both beans are created by spring, although only one bean is injected into the `TextEditor`.

In spring its perfectly fine to have more than one bean of the same type or beans that implement the same interface (think about listeners - there can be many of them) - so spring container will create them all during the application start.

If you want to inject one of those beans however into another bean (like `TextEditor` in your case), spring won't have a clue which one to inject, that's why you they've added a "qualifier" feature.

Another note, you've by mistake put a `@Component` annotation on the configuration class, instead you should use `@Configuration` annotation to specify that this class contains a series of beans definitions (that you indeed declare with `@Bean` annotation). Although the "configuration" is also a component (managed by spring) - spring still treats it in a significantly different way than regular beans.

And yet another note: although its not directly related to your question, it seems like you're mixing 2 styles of configurations in the code snippet you've provided: the style with `@Qualifier/@Autowired` (this way was added in spring 2.5 if I'm not mistaken) and the style of java configurations: `@Configuration` class with `@Bean`-s in it.

You can avoid using autowire altogether and inject the dependencies via constructor called from java config like this:

```
@Configuration
public class HelloWorldConfig {
    @Bean
    public HelloWorld helloWorld(){
        return new HelloWorld();
    }
    @Bean
    public TextEditor textEditor(@Qualifier("a") SpellChecker spellChecker){ // note the dependency here
        return new TextEditor(spellChecker);
    }
    @Bean(name="a")
    public SpellChecker spellChecker(){
        return new SpellChecker();
    }
    @Bean(name="b")
    public SpellChecker spellChecker1(){
        return new SpellChecker();
    }
}

// the TextEditor Class should have a constructor with one argument:

public class TextEditor {
  private final SpellChecker spellChecker;
  public TextEditor(SpellChecker spellChecker) {
     this.spellChecker = spellChecker;
  }
  ...
}

// or if you use lombok library:

@AllArgsConstructor
public class TextEditor {
  private final SpellChecker spellChecker;
  ...
}
```

Now note, that your "business classes" are not even aware of spring all the "resolution" (usage of qualifier and injection rules) is done in spring configuration which is a special class anyway.